# Install vue template over Laravel project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, templates

I bought a vue template. I want to install it over laravel but I getting a lot of 'Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/path';' errors.

I have tried to add a resolve alias to webpack but with no luck.

Any ideeas how should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you fail to put it at the end .vue() in webpack.mix.js file

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
```